# How to get values of attribute of an html in javascript for validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```
<input type='text' id='firstname' data-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]+$/"  data-message="For your name please use alphabets only" required="required" /><br />
```

For the above code i want the value of the first name to be compared with the data-pattern. So how would we proceed with that in javascript

Comment: Maybe you could use `pattern="[a-zA-Z]+"` instead.

Comment: i want to compare both the values the pattern with the value of the name field

Comment: <input type='text' id='firstname'  /><br />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var firstName= document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var regExp= /^[a-zA-Z]+$/g;
    if(regExp.test(firstName) == false){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="For your name please use alphabets only";
     }
     
    return false;
}
</script>

Answer (score 1):

```css
input[type="text"]:valid{
color:green;
}
input[type="text"]:invalid{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='firstname' pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"  data-message="For your name please use alphabets only" required="required" /><br />
```